# Filtering params in rails active jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, parameter-passing

I am creating background job for sending registration email to the user after they have been created an account, I am using devise for authentication, I am enqueuing a job `RegistrationMailer.send_login_credentials(self, password).deliver_later` at user model (as there is no way to get the password after save I need to send password as parameter to active job while enqueue a mailer job), 
But the parameters are getting printed while enqueuing and while processing the job, Is there any way to filter these password parameter, Or any safer way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create an *initializer* `config/initializers/active_job_patch.rb` and patch the `args_info` metjhod to not print the arguments.

```
require 'active_job/logging'
class ActiveJob::Logging::LogSubscriber
  private def args_info(job)
    ''
  end
end
```

Comment: This won't display all the argument?!

Comment: Yes, it won't display all the arguments.

Comment: We may not know Which job is enqueued, and what is being performed, If we do like this

Comment: Alternative approach is to use temporary storage for passwords like redis `SETEX`. Against user id, set the password and pick the password from redis when the job is processing. The key will then expire and be removed from memory.

Comment: Will look into it, Thanks

Comment: @Aarthi that's also a viable option, Rails has `ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor` using which you can do so; however, you will need to make sure your production secret for that is safe, because getting a log file and the secret will potentially leak all the passwords.